# How to extract Android version 3 signing certificate from the APK

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature

From Version 2 onwards, the certificate file doesn't reside in `META-INF/CERT.RSA` , it is somewhere in the region above "APK Sig Block 42". I tried to use keytool to extract, but it doesn't detect version 2 and version 3 signatures.

My goal is to extract the certificate - are their any tools or method to achieve the same for version 2 signature on apk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apksigner` which is shipped as part of the Android SDK tools, with the `--verbose` option.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner

Comment: That works, thanks. But I couldn't find any option to extract it as crt file

Comment: Did you look at the `--print-certs` flag?

Answer (score 0):

The full syntax of the command in Windows is:

```
"C:\Android-Sdk\build-tools\<version>\apksigner.bat" verify --print-certs --v <your_apk_file>.apk
```

where  is one of your installed build tool version.

Unfortunately, this command is not designed to extract the cert from APK.